# Decompose metrics and model as separate columns and rows

Tags: pyspark

How do I convert Spark table `df_metrics_1` to table `df_metrics_2`?

Dataframe 1:

```
df_metrics_1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2.0,3.0,1.0, 4.0 ,"A"), 
                                    (4, 2.0,2.0,2.0, 1.0, "A"), 
                                    (7,5.0,8.0,5.0, 6.0, "B")], 
                                    ["id", "mae_modelA", "mae_modelB", "mse_modelA", "mse_modelB", "class"])
df_metrics_1.show(truncate=False)
```

Dataframe 2:

```
df_metrics_2 = spark.createDataFrame([("A",'modelA', 1, 2.0, 1.0), 
                                      ("A", 'modelB', 1, 3.0, 4.0), 
                                      ("A",'modelA', 4, 2.0, 2.0), 
                                      ("A", 'modelB', 4, 2.0, 1.0), 
                                      ("B",'modelA',7 ,5.0, 5.0),
                                      ("B",'mobelB', 7, 8.0, 6.0)], 
                                      ["class", "model_nm", "id", "mae", "mse"])
df_metrics_2.show(truncate=False)
```

How do I get the second table from the fist table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expand dataframe columns to rows, get the model name, type and pivot for the type.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    (1,2.0,3.0,1.0, 4.0 ,"A"), 
    (4, 2.0,2.0,2.0, 1.0, "A"), 
    (7,5.0,8.0,5.0, 6.0, "B")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "mae_modelA", "mae_modelB", "mse_modelA", "mse_modelB", "class"])

cols = df.columns

df.rdd.flatMap(lambda r: [(r[0], r[5], cols[i], r[i]) for i in range(1, 5)]) \
  .toDF(['id', 'class', 'model', 'value']) \
  .withColumn('model_nm', f.split('model', '_')[1]) \
  .withColumn('model_type', f.split('model', '_')[0]) \
  .groupBy('class', 'model_nm', 'id') \
  .pivot('model_type') \
  .max('value') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+-----+--------+---+---+---+
|class|model_nm|id |mae|mse|
+-----+--------+---+---+---+
|A    |modelA  |4  |2.0|2.0|
|A    |modelB  |1  |3.0|4.0|
|B    |modelA  |7  |5.0|5.0|
|A    |modelA  |1  |2.0|1.0|
|A    |modelB  |4  |2.0|1.0|
|B    |modelB  |7  |8.0|6.0|
+-----+--------+---+---+---+
```